# Moment: the user should be able to perform X as long as the current time and date is max 30 minutes before the requested time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, momentjs

I tried doing this

```
const currentTime = moment(moment().format('MMMM DD YYYY, h:mm a'));
        const timeDifference = moment.duration(currentTime.diff(details.requestedStartTimestamp)).asMinutes();
```

But I'm getting confused because timeDifference is displaying negative if the date is today or a future date and positive if it's in the past, which forces me to add this condition:

if(timeDifference <= -30) {perform x}

Answer (score 0):

`time1.diff(time2)` means `time1 - time2`, so getting the negative result for future date is correct.

On a side note, you don't need to format your time to get the `moment` object for now.

To get the result you want, this code could work:

```
const now = moment();
const requestedTime = moment(details.requestedStartTimestamp);
const diff = requestedTime.diff(now, 'minutes');

if (diff >= 30) {
  // ...
}
```